# When to use Skolem constant and a skolem function?

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic

> ∀x [∃y Animal (y) ∧ ¬Loves(x, y)] ∨ [∃z Loves(z, x)]

In the **CNF conversion** process, at the **skolemize** step, why the above statement use **skolem function** rather than a **constant** like 'A' or 'B' for ∃z Loves(z, x) part.

The [book's](https://books.google.lk/books?id=8jZBksh-bUMC) answer is

> ∀x [Animal (F(x)) ∧ ¬Loves(x, F(x))] ∨ Loves(G(x), x)

Could someone elaborate the explanation given in there?

Should we always need to read the meaning before deciding what to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [Skolem normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form).

If the existential quantifier is inside the scope of one or more universal quantifiers, we need a *function* symbol.

If the existential quantifier is not inside the scope of an universal quantifiers, we need a *constant* symbol.

The "intuition" is: for $\exists x \ P(x)$ we can choose e new *constant* symbol $c$ and "name" with it the existsing object such that $P$ holds of it.

For the case $\forall x \ \exists y \ P(y)$ we have to write $\forall x \ P(f(x))$ because we know that "for every $x$ there is an $y$ such that" and this does not mean that we have a unique $y$ in the universe of discourse, but only an $y$ for every $x$, i.e. something like "$f: x \to y=f(x)$".

Comment: +1. An observation for the OP: we can view constants as $0$-ary functions. When we do this, everything becomes nice and uniform: the Skolem function we attach to an existential quantifier has arity [the number of universal quantifiers before it in Skolem normal form]. If that number is $0$, then our Skolem function is $0$-ary, that is, is a constant.

Comment: You wrote "this does not mean that we have a unique y in the universe", but what I don't understand is: For the expression ∃x P(x) , there can be different xs that satisfy the sentence too, why is a constant enough for this case then?

Comment: @unlut - Consider this example in $\mathbb N$ : $\exists x (0 < x)$; for sure we have $(0 < 1)$ but $1$ is not the only number satisfying the formula.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA sorry, in my previous comment I meant to say "skolem constant" instead of constant.